# "Piped" core pattern is not creating core dumps inside docker container

Tags: docker, coredump, busybox

Consider this simple "piped" core pattern:

```
vagrant@myhost:~$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern                        
|/var/core-manager.sh %t
```

having this, also simplified, core manager script:

```
vagrant@myhost:~$ cat /var/core-manager.sh 
#!/bin/bash
(
  file=/tmp/mycore.$1
  cat > $file < /dev/stdin
)
```

Now reproduce and retrieve a core dump in a linux host:

```
vagrant@myhost:~$ ls -lrt /tmp/mycore*
total 0
vagrant@myhost:~$ ulimit -c unlimited
vagrant@myhost:~$ sleep 100 &
[1] 16647
vagrant@myhost:~$ kill -SIGSEGV 16647
[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped) sleep 100
vagrant@myhost:~$ ls -lrt /tmp/mycore*
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 385024 Jan 28 18:42 /tmp/mycore.1580233332
```

Now, reproduce it inside a container, let's say, busybox:

(the core pattern, as many of you may know, is inherited by container, and although ulimit is not, because it depends on the calling shell, probably 'unlimited' is a default in busybox shells because the thing is that i have unlimited ulimit for core size inside the container doing 'nothing', and that's what i actually want).

```
vagrant@myhost:~$ docker run -it --rm busybox
/ # cat << EOF > /var/core-manager.sh
> #!/bin/bash
> (
>   file=/tmp/mycore.$1
>   cat > $file < /dev/stdin
> )
> EOF
/ # chmod a+x /var/core-manager.sh
/ # cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/var/core-manager.sh %t
/ # ulimit -c
unlimited
/ # sleep 100 &
/ # kill -SIGSEGV %1
/ # 
[1]+  Segmentation fault (core dumped) sleep 100
/ # ls -lrt /tmp/mycore*
ls: /tmp/mycore*: No such file or directory
```

I added a+x permissions to the core manager script, just in case, however i don't think so that it is necessary (i'm lost regarding how asynchronous system tasks like core dumping are behaving). Anyway, as you can see, **core dump is not created**.

Regular path location for core pattern works perfectly within containers (of course on host), then this makes me think that something in docker is restricting the use of this kind of "piped" core patterns. Or perhaps it is something i can't see now.

Any idea ?
Thank u very much!

Comment: The core dump was created, just not in the container's file system. It should be in `/tmp` _on the host_. Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/565788/core-file-may-or-may-not-escape-docker-container-depending-on-the-core-pattern

Comment: it's true !! and the /var/core-manager.sh inside the busybox is not used (indeed it was wrong because of the $1 expansion to "", i should be \$1 in my original question). The thing is that the behaviour changes when the core pattern is a regular path (non piped): in that case, the core is generated inside the docker file system, AND NOT OUTSIDE. Anyway, this change confused to me, thank you for clarification.